# How to run Laravel Migrations, then Seeders, then more Migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

I am re-building my Laravel app and, in the process, redesigning the data model.

1. I have a subset of my Migrations (35) I need to run to create the data model in the new app.
2. Then, I need to run some Seeders to populate the new tables.
3. Some of the new tables (12) have a column "old_id" where I place the "id" from the old data model to handle foreign keys/joins. I run a series of Update statements to change the foreign key values from the "old_id" to the new id.
4. Then, I want to run additional Migrations (12) that drop the "old_id" columns.

Here are the commands I'm running currently that do everything for me - clear DB, run migrations, populate data, and update keys.

```
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --seeder=DatabaseSeeder
```

I'm trying to find a way to only run a portion of my Migrations prior to executing DatabaseSeeder, and then run the remaining Migrations after (or as the last step of) the DatabaseSeeder.

Contents of DatabaseSeeder::class:

```
public function run()
{
$this->call([
  // Seeders to populate data
  UserSeeder::class,
  AssociationSeeder::class,
  ... lots more classes ...
  // Last Seeder class executes Update statements to update foreign keys
  DatabaseUpdateSeeder::class, 
]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have a similar requirement on one of my projects, and the way we handle that is multiple `php artisan migrate` commands. That command has a parameter `--path` that you can use to specify which migrations to run. If you split the migrations into a subfolders, like `/migrations/batch-one` and `migrations/batch-two`, then you can run `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/batch-one`, then `php artisan db:seed`, then `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/batch-two`, or something similar. The way you have it right now, _all_ migrations will be run before seeding.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis . I ended up finding another way and posted it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following the advice of the comment on the original post. While my previous "answer" also works, this is the *right* way to do it; separating round 1 and round 2 Migrations, and not executing Seeders from a Migration.

Here are my 2 commands (could be 3 if I wanted a separate command in the middle that only executes the Seeder), but adding the Seeder on the end of the command is supported syntax.

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --path=/database/migrations/batch-one --seed --seeder=DatabaseSeeder

php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/batch-two
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by creating a Migration that calls my DatabaseSeeder. Here is how: https://owenconti.com/posts/calling-laravel-seeders-from-migrations

Then, after that Migration, I just have an additional Migration(s) to drop the "old_id" columns.

I also want to call out the comment from Tim on my original post with an alternative that would also work, but required multiple statements from the command line.

Comment: This works too, although logic for migrating and seeding _should_ be kept separate. And yes, while it would require multiple commands, you can simply concatenate them into a single command, like `php artisan ... && php artisan ... && php artisan ...`. Glad you got it working though 

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis for calling out the *right* way to do it. I want to make sure I'm following best practices when possible, and this is one of them, so I went ahead and separated the migrations and seeders (I added a new "answer" which I will mark as the correct one.) Thanks again.